# *Beginner* - How can I clean up this code?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that takes the files saved in a folder, renames them, deletes the old files and moves the new ones to another folder (Haven't got to this last bit yet but I'm working it).

Being new I would be interested to know how this can be cleaned up. I know this needs to be iterated but since there are slight variations in the file names I can't quite wrap my head around how to account for that.

```
import os
cwd = os.chdir('C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\C008_Start')

#variable for raw file spreadsheets
Monthly1 = "(1 of 4) Report View of CDRL 10 Consumption - Transaction Date.xlsx"
Monthly2 = "(2 of 4) Report View of CDRL 10 Consumption - Transaction Date.xlsx"
Monthly3 = "(3 of 4) Report View of CDRL 10 Consumption - Transaction Date.xlsx"
Monthly4 = "(4 of 4) Report View of CDRL 10 Consumption - Transaction Date.xlsx"

#variables for renamed spreadsheets
rename1 = "CDRL 10 Consumption - Monthly 1 of 4.xlsx"
rename2 = "CDRL 10 Consumption - Monthly 2 of 4.xlsx"
rename3 = "CDRL 10 Consumption - Monthly 3 of 4.xlsx"
rename4 = "CDRL 10 Consumption - Monthly 4 of 4.xlsx"

#renaming the files in folder
folder = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\C008_Start')

if Monthly1 in folder:
    os.rename(Monthly1, rename1)
if Monthly2 in folder:
    os.rename(Monthly2, rename2)
if Monthly3 in folder:
    os.rename(Monthly3, rename3)
if Monthly4 in folder:
    os.rename(Monthly4, rename4)

#Removing last months files
cwd = os.chdir('C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\Python')
dest = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\Python')

if rename1 in dest:
    os.remove(rename1)
if rename2 in dest:
    os.remove(rename2)
if rename3 in dest:
    os.remove(rename3)
if rename4 in dest:
    os.remove(rename4)
```

Comment: Put the variables in lists and use for-loops.

Comment: Example: `for i in range(4): print(f"CDRL 10 Consumption - Monthly {i+1} of 4.xlsx")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a template that might work for you.

```
import os
cwd = os.chdir('C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\C008_Start')

monthlyText = "Report View of CDRL 10 Consumption - Transaction Date.xlsx"
nameText = "CDRL 10 Consumption - Monthly "

#variable for raw file spreadsheets
#variables for renamed spreadsheets
monthly = []
newNames = []
for i in range(4):
    monthly.append("(" + str(i+1) + " of 4) " + monthlyTex)
    newNames.append(nameText + str(i+1) + " of 4.xlsx")

#renaming the files in folder
folder = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\C008_Start')

for month,rename in zip(monthly,newNames):
    if month in folder:
        os.rename(month, rename)

#Removing last months files
cwd = os.chdir('C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\Python')
dest = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\Python')

for rename in newName:
    if rename in dest:
        os.remove(rename)
```

I am just creating lists that contain you variables, and then looping over them.

Comment: Makes sense now that I can see it, never knew about "ZIP" either. Thank you!

Comment: This may work for the example shown but isn't very flexible. Consider what would happen if there were files with the format of '(1 of 5)...'? You'd have to make three changes to the code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pattern to the filenames - i.e., one can be derived from the other. Using the *glob* module you can search specifically for files matching a particular pattern then construct the new filename based on what's returned by *glob*

You can also [attempt to] remove files from the desktop folder in the same loop. Use a try/except on FileNotFoundError and ignore any such exception.

Note how the paths are joined so that absolute paths are used throughout and hence no need to change working directory.

```
from glob import glob
import re
from os.path import join
from os import rename, remove

SRC = 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\C008_Start'
DESKTOP = 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\Python'

for file in glob(join(SRC, '(* of *) Report View of CDRL 10 Consumption - Transaction Date.xlsx')):
    f, t, *_ = re.findall('\d+', file)
    target = join(SRC, f'CDRL 10 Consumption - Monthly {f} of {t}.xlsx')
    rename(file, target)
    try:
        remove(join(DESKTOP, target))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```